# Automatically launch electron app when OBS launches

Tags: javascript, electron, launch, obs

I am developing a companion application in electron.js for OBS. I want this companion app to automatically launch when OBS launches. One way I was thinking of doing this was simply by having helper app launch on computer startup and just check to see if OBS is running (say, every 5 seconds). If it is, then it launches the main application. However, I don't think that may sit well with the users. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I'd imagine the answer might be operating system dependent, so you might want to share which one you are using.

Comment: I would think you can create a plugin in obs that sends the command to os to start your application.

Comment: I guess you could try searching for and substituting all OBS shortcuts the user might use with your own "seem-alike" shortcuts that would point into your main application which  would then proceed into running the actual OBS executable

Comment: You could also look into symlinks and substitute perhaps the OBS program folder to point to your own folder so that all shortcuts or direct calls to the OBS executable would be instead pointing at your program on another folder, the same which would then call the real OBS

Comment: I'd like to release this software for both macos and windows